# Updating/Marking duplicate entries with SP's in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a program in Python3 that generates alot of data, I want to store this data in MySQL using a python script that calls Stored Procedures that contain queries to do stuff.

I have a very large database with +/- 3.5 mill. entries, in this database there are a few duplicates that I sort out using this query:

```
SELECT oligoSequence FROM Oligos GROUP BY oligoSequence HAVING COUNT(oligoSequence) > 1;
```

Now I got the following Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_mark_duplicate_oligos() 
BEGIN 
SELECT oligoSequence FROM Oligos GROUP BY oligoSequence HAVING count(oligoSequence) > 1;
END // 
DELIMITER ;
```

As for my tabel, I got a tinyint (isUniqueProbe) that I want to change from 0 to 1 if it is a duplicate.

```
CREATE TABLE Oligos 
(   gene_id             varchar(30)     not null, 
oligoStartposition  int             not null, 
oligoSequence       varchar(25)     not null, 
incubationTemp      decimal(5,2)    not null, 
isUniqueProbe       tinyint(1), 
primary key(gene_id, oligoStartposition), 
foreign key(gene_id) references Genes(id) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But I'm fairyly new to MySQL and I can't seem to get the update statement working in the Stored Procedure, maybe I've been at it for too long but if someone could shed some light on this I will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance,
Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't seem relevant to this question, nor the fact that it's in a stored procedure.

```
UPDATE Oligos o
JOIN (SELECT oligoSequence
      FROM Oligos
      GROUP BY oligoSequence
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dups
ON o.oligoSequence = dups.oligoSequence
SET isUniqueProbe = 1
```

You should index `oligoSequence` to make this more efficient.

Comment: Sorry just wanted to provide enough information. It works, thanks allot! I just wanted to ask, since I also want to understand this, what does dups do/mean? Just a variable so store the select in?

Comment: It's an alias for the subquery. All subqueries used in joins are required to have aliases, and it's also needed in this case to disambiguate the two `oligoSequence` columns.